# Do you know any tricks/hacks to perform arithmetic operations with shift registers?

Tags: digital-logic, shift-register

The trivial case is to use SRL to express multiplication:
`val * 2^num => val sll num`
`val sll 2 + val sll 8 => val * 10`

Do you know any other cases like for instance:
`val*(2^num) + 1 => ?`

How do you use SRLs?

Comment: Are we considering operations that can be performed by only one instruction?

Comment: Exactly. In that case: not possible. Otherwise: use `(val sll num)+val`. Also, you probably mean `val*2^(num+1)` (watch the brackets!)

Comment: Also, what architecture(s) are we considering?

Comment: Ah, an edit. Well, `val*(2^num)+1 = (val sll num) + 1`. _Are you sure the brackets are right?_

Comment: @camil what if val is 64bit long and you want to get rid off adder (it will slow down things)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with adder. This is the fastest way: simply shift val and after that set the LSB.

Comment: You really need to edit this question for it to be answerable. What instruction set(s) are we considering? What other sorts of trick(s) are we considering? Why do you say SRL is a trivial case of multiplication, but then use SLL in your example?

Comment: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: http://www.hackersdelight.org/

Comment: @starblue great links! thanks a lot. I was looking for such infos.

Comment: @PhilFrost I do not ask how to multiply or provide with answer to any specific question. I am asking how did you use shift registers in your design other than mentioned above - do you know any tricks/hacks to do math on bits with shift registers?

Answer (score 1):

It is relatively easy to construct a circuit which will take two LSB-first serial data streams along with a signal which identifies the first bit, and output the sum or difference as a serial data stream.  A fixed amount of circuitry will be able to handle inputs of arbitrary size.

There are two general approaches to performing multiplication using shift registers.  If one wishes to multiply an N-bit number by an M-bit number, one may use relatively simple hardware to perform the operation in approximately NxM steps using the above "adder" plus some circuitry to coordinate things (assuming external circuitry can supply one of the multiplicands a bit at a time, can supply the other multiplicand repeatedly, and can feed back the partial product).  A much faster approach requires the use of M single-bit addition stages, and can reduce the required time to approximately N+M (the length of the result).  Note that even the faster approach does not require the use of fast carry-propagation logic; each stage can latch its carry output and accept it as a carry input for the next step.

Comment: Could you provide more info regarding the last approach?

Comment: Basically, the idea is that one multiplicand is stored in a parallel-readout register, and on each step, one computes "partial_product = (partial_product >> 1) + multiplicand1 * (one bit of multiplcand2)".  The bits that fall off the end of partial_product form the result.  The small "multiply" step effectively means that each bit of multiplcand2 selects between adding multiplicand1 or adding nothing.  One could use a conventional carry chain for the addition, but as an alternative one may simply latch the carry out of each stage and feed it into the same stage on the next cycle.